# How to get response back within azure function which is calling an azure automation runnbook via webhoook

Tags: azure, azure-automation, runbook, azure-function-app

I have a https triggered function app which is calling a webhook which internally is calling a runbook.  Runbook is running on hybrid worker group and based on the inputs it's returns some output is there any way to get the response back to the azure function without storing the runbook output in any temporary storage.